# File Iterator is moving phantom files

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

The app script I'm running to move files with a certain name in the title to a new folder is copying the same files every time the script is run. Removing the files from the source folder doesn't seem to work.

Form responses are collected in a spreadsheet and an add-on is used to put the responses into a form that generates a new Google doc. The Google Docs is for all of our various buildings, which each have a unique name. The script should iterate through the file names and add the file to the specific buildings folder and then remove it from the folder that has every building altogether. When I run the script, it works, but on subsequent runs, all of the files that were copied before keep getting copied again with any new files in addition to it.

```
function movePittsburghFiles() {
  var sourceFolder=DriveApp.getFolderById('taqwdGs4MUEyUEl1WQ8');
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('taqwV085WTVtdTdf');

  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains "3N - Pittsburgh Weekly"');
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    destFolder.addFile(file);
    sourceFolder.removeFile(file);
  }
```

The script works, but it keeps finding the same files in the source folder that were already moved in previous runs of the code and copying them again. When I go to the folder in Google Drive, those files are not listed, but somehow the script keeps finding them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

- You're searching the whole drive, When you're  calling `.searchFiles()` on `DriveApp`.

#### Solution:

- Call `.searchFiles()` on the `sourceFolder` instead.

#### Snippet:

```
var files = sourceFolder.searchFiles('title contains "3N - Pittsburgh Weekly"');
```

#### References:

- [Folder#SearchFiles](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#searchFiles(String))